# Como usar o artigo “o” ou “a” junto com uma sigla em Inglês?

Tags: concordância, artigos-definidos

Qual a maneira correta de se utilizar o artigo "o" ou "a" junto com uma sigla em Inglês? Por exemplo, o correto é "a CPU" ou "o CPU" (***C***entral **P**rocessing **U**nit)? Existe alguma regra a ser seguida?

Comment: deveria ser considerada duplicada mesmo não estando no mesmo idioma da outra questão?

Comment: Abre discussão no meta. Eu acho que sim.

Comment: http://meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/36/115